# Twitter following relation using Rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm working on a project that has almost the same user relations as Twitter. User can be a fan of another user (following) and a user has many fans (followers).

How can I write this using Mongoid and Rails 3.1?

Is it enough with the User model?

```
class User
  inc...
  inc...

  has_many :following, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :followers, class_name: 'User'

end
```

Anyone done this before? I found some old posts about this issue but they were old and outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :following
has_and_belongs_to_many :following, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :followers
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it uses arrays, meaning that removing a follower or determining if somebody follows somebody else will be O(n). This could be a problem for users with lots and lots of followers. Also, with Mongo there is a limit on the size of a document, so storing them internally could reach that limit for users with lots of followers.

Comment: I think he was just asking about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a follow and followable gem, you can try it out if it fits your bill.

https://github.com/alecguintu/mongoid_follow